# Express not sending response when controller contains Axios or Node HTTPS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webhooks

I am integrating with an external webhook (via Wix.com's API), and I am having an issue where the presence of an Axios (or raw Node HTTP / HTTPS) request is preventing the response from being sent.

Here is my controller code:

```js
const https = require('https')

const request = config =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(config, res => {
      let data = ''

      res.on('data', d => {
        console.log('GOT DATA:', d)
        data += d
      })

      res.on('close', () => {
        resolve(data.toString())
      })
    })

    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })  

    req.end()
  })  

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('BEFORE REQUEST')

  const result = await request({
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
  })  

  console.log('GOT RESULT')

  return res.send({ success: true })
}
```

And I'm seeing the following logs:

```
BEFORE REQUEST
GOT RESULT
```

But I'm not getting a response (inspecting via Ngrok).

**Note:** when I replay the request via Ngrok, or manually send it via `curl` it does send a response, so it's only producing this error when receiving the request from the Webhook provider. I haven't been able to figure out what is different about the request from the webhook provider vs. the replayed request, which should theoretically be exactly the same.

When I comment out the `await request(...)` lines, then I do see a resonse.

So, my question is, are there any known interactions between Node HTTP / HTTPS and Express's `res.send()` function? It seems that after calling the HTTP / HTTPS functions, `res.send` just stops working.

Answer (score -1):

If you pass your `handler` function to route:
`app.post('/webhook', handler)`
Then you should not `return` the `res.send` but you have to invoke it.
So your last line should look like this:

`res.send({ success: true })`

=========================================

Previous answer totally bad:

Your `request` function is not `async`. Correct is:

```
const request = async (config) => ...
```

I use same pattern without any issues.

Comment: This `request` function is just a promise-based wrapped I wrote around Node's `https` library. That library (to my knowledge) does not support promises out of the box, so that's why I wrapped it like this.